# Does くだく mean “destroy”? What does いい mean at the beginning of a line?

Tags: translation, meaning, manga

[image: speech bubble 1]
[image: speech bubble 2]

Would the following be a good translation of the text in the above two speech bubbles?

> "*Everything in this universe is composed of atoms. Destroying
>   something is equivalent to destroying the atoms that compose it*"

Also, I'm especially interested in knowing if the Japanese text is implying that atoms are completely destroyed/annihilated or if the atoms are separated or pulverized (but not literally/completely destroyed). I'm having troubles on my own... =/

---

Here is a transcription of the two speech bubbles, in case you can't see the images:

> 「この
>   　大宇宙にあるもの
>   　すべてが
>   　原子でできている
>   　のよ」
>
> 「いい　破壊する
>   　ということの
>   　根本は　原子を
>   　くだく
>   　ということなの」

Comment: Was it on purpose that you left the 「いい」 part untranslated?  That would ironically be the most difficult part despite its look if one weren't fluent, though.

Comment: Maybe... Ok, yes. And yeah, I'm not fluent unfortunately

Comment: You should really include something about the specific problem in the title. Stack Exchange questions should help others besides the person first asking. Having generic titles does not help this happen.

Answer (score 3):

The translation of the first sentence sounds fine.

For the second one, "destroy" may be too general for 「くだく」 and "be equivalent to" sounds a little bit different to 「…の根本｛こんぽん｝は」. My suggestion is something like "The essence of destroying something is shattering the atoms that compose it." (I'm not a native English speaker, the wording may be awkward...)

Since it's literally saying "shattering the atoms", i.e.「原子｛げんし｝をくだく」, not "shattering something into atoms", 「原子｛げんし｝`に`くだく」as in 「粉々｛こなごな｝`に`くだく」 and 「微塵｛みじん｝`に`くだく」　may be more appropriate for the "atoms are separated" reading.

As to the 「いい」 that 非回答者 has pointed out, I guess it's something like "understand?" or "all right?" used when a teacher is explaining something to his/her student(s) or in other similar circumstances.

Comment: Depending on the greater context (beyond just these two speech bubbles), "break down" or "disintegrate" might also be viable translations for くだく.

Comment: @Noir Precisely.  This 「いい」 is pronounced quite differently from the "regular" adjective 「いい」 as in 「非回答者さんはいい人です。」.  It is pronounced 「い + い」 in two syllables with a rising intonation towards the end.  The "regular" 「いい」 meaning "good" is pronounced like 「いー」 in one syllable.

Comment: @非回答者 Thanks for adding that important point! My perception is that, in this case, more precisely speaking, the first syllable is with a falling intonation while the second is with a rising one.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Thanks for the input. Here's a link to the page- http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/741/2229038078.jpg .Plus here's the previous page- http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/741/2486490699.jpg
.Context here is main character basically trying to break a rock, and if I understood correctly they do this by concentrating on a point and attacking the atoms that compose everything (in this case the atoms of the rock). There's another mention later- http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/741/5346339000.jpg .And looks to me like it talks about the power of Saints to break atoms

Comment: @非回答者 Thanks for elaborating on the 「いい」 part ...Interesting how intonation can make such a difference. Reminds me of Spanish with its accent marks etc.

Comment: @Noir Thanks for your answer. If I understood correctly, "destroy" can be used but in general sense. And 「くだく」 more specifically refers to shatter/break/pulverize. 

Hmm, which of the following do you guys prefer?

"*Everything in this universe is composed of atoms. The essence of destroying something lies in shattering the atoms that compose it. Understood?*"

Or instead for the second part-

"*The essence of destroying something lies in pulverizing the atoms that compose it. Understood?*"

Or-

"*The essence of shattering something lies in shattering the atoms that compose it. Understand?*"

Comment: @Mackk I think you got what I meant as to 「くだく」 and I'm sorry that I mistranslated 「破壊」(i.e. destroy) into "shattering" <@_@> (have had that corrected). I'm not a native English speaker, it's hard for me to see the difference that "pulverizing v.s. shattering" and "Understood v.s. Understand" can make here. I'm definitely glad to see others elaborating on their nuance.